# OneSignal does not showing notification when app is in foreground

Tags: push-notification, onesignal, foreground, foregroundnotification

I entegrated my flutter app with onesignal, and it's working perfect when app is in background, but in foreground it's receiving notification but not showing it any idea why?

**log**

```
flutter: OSNotificationReceivedEvent complete with notification: Instance of 'OSNotification'
VERBOSE: finishProcessingNotification: Fired!
VERBOSE: Notification display type: 7
VERBOSE: notificationReceived called! opened: NO
VERBOSE: finishProcessingNotification: call completionHandler with options: 7
```

**Foreground handler**

```
  OneSignal.shared.setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler(
      (OSNotificationReceivedEvent event) {
    event.complete(event.notification);
  });
```